# Creating a primary key/sequence as Varchar

Tags: mysql, sequence

I've got an existing table in a big existing project. This table has a primary key defined as a VARCHAR (which cannot easily be changed to an int)

Now I have to create new entries for this table and create new primary keys automatically.

The first and poor idea is to try to use autoincrement on this Varchar field. That fails, of course.
My second idea was to create an own int sequence and create that key of of this sequence (e. g. 'XXX' + '000001'). But there are no sequences in MySQL. :(

So what can I do? Are there any solutions?

Cheers

Chris

Comment: First of - I suggest you to think - what is harder: to maintain such kind of "solution" (I mean miracle work with varchar) or to change your column to integer. Also, what prevents you from declaring your new integer column as auto_increment ?

Comment: Ok, what I meant to say with 'which cannot easily be changed to an int' was that it cannot be easily changed to an int. So that's why I'm posting this issue.

Comment: Then explain what restrictions should fit that "solution"

Comment: My idea was to create my own key out of a fixed, non-taken varchar prefixe (there are many, e. g. 'AAA') plus a consecutive, formatted number, converted to a varchar e. g. '00000001')

Comment: It all is bad in terms of concurrent connections. You'll not be able to emulate proper work in that case (so you'll have a risk that two records will have same key value with all the consequences)

Comment: So there is absolutly no equivalent to a sequence? Not even a "sequence pattern"???

Comment: No, nothing common in full sense. That's weak part of MySQL. Only sequence-like thing is auto_increment, but for some reasons you don't want to use that on additional column